# Azure Functions for Python - Dependencies cannot be found

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I've got a function I wanted to elevate to Azure Functions using Continous Delivery as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=python

When starting my function, I get the following error:

`Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.keyvault'. Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 284, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.8/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 76, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "/home/site/wwwroot/CaseDB_Functions/__init__.py", line 4, in <module> from .case_crawler.federal_cases import FederalCases File "/home/site/wwwroot/CaseDB_Functions/case_crawler/federal_cases.py", line 1, in <module> from shared_code import blob_handler File "/home/site/wwwroot/shared_code/blob_handler.py", line 5, in <module> from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient`

(Note: It's not a specific problem with just this dependency, it's just the first dependency that's getting imported in my code - already switched the first import with diffrent packages, which basically resulted in the same error, just with the other package)

I've already tried my code in diffrent environments (also Ubuntu, which should be the same image Azure functions is using) and always used venv. My code always worked fine locally, so it seems I'm missing something while building and publishing my code to Azure (which is done via Azure Pipelines).

My requirements.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.4
astroid==2.5.1
azure-common==1.1.26
azure-core==1.12.0
azure-cosmos==4.2.0
azure-functions==1.6.0
azure-identity==1.5.0
azure-keyvault==4.1.0
azure-keyvault-certificates==4.2.1
azure-keyvault-keys==4.3.1
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.2.0
azure-storage-blob==12.8.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2020.12.5
cffi==1.14.5
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.4
cryptography==3.4.6
decorator==4.4.2
distlib==0.3.1
filelock==3.0.12
idna==2.10
isodate==0.6.0
isort==5.7.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.5.2
lxml==4.6.2
mccabe==0.6.1
msal==1.10.0
msrest==0.6.21
oauthlib==3.1.0
pipenv==2020.11.15
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==2.0.1
pylint==2.7.2
requests==2.25.1
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
self==2020.12.3
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.2
toml==0.10.2
urllib3==1.26.3
virtualenv==20.4.2
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
wrapt==1.12.1
```

My azure-pipelines.yml:

```
# Python Function App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Python function app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux function app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/python

trigger:
- master

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: '<subscription-Id>'

  # Function app name
  functionAppName: '<functionAppName>'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

  # Working Directory
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64 --output ./bin
        fi
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Build extensions'

    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.7'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.7 # Functions V2 supports Python 3.9 as of today

    - bash: |
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt

      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install application dependencies'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(workingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

(Note: Of course, in the real file my Subscription-Id and the FunctionAppName are included).

While building, I get no errors from Azure pipeline. All dependencies are installed packaged. I even checked by downloading the .zip-file myself. Honestly, to me it just seems like Azure Functions is ignoring my venv. Can anyone help?

Comment: This is an issue that quite similar with yours: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/827

Comment: Firstly, please follow the troubleshooting steps in this wiki about [Module Not Found Issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/wiki/Module-Not-Found-Issues). If you still have this issue, you can create a issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue). In addition, please try to change pip install -r requirements.txt line in the YAML file to pip install --target="$(workingDirectory)/.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r requirements.txt. Hope it helps.